# AS compatibility: “.. from T as a..” works in MySQL and SQL Server, not Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, syntax

I try to work out this problem in hackerrank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/symmetric-pairs/problem

the following code works in MySQL and MS SQL Server but not Oracle. Any body tells me why?

```
with T as (
    select x,y, row_number() over (order by x,y) as rnum from functions
)
select distinct a.x,a.y from T as a, T as b 
where a.x = b.y and b.x=a.y and a.x<=a.y and a.rnum!=b.rnum 
order by a.x,a.y;
```

It seems that if I delete "AS" then it works in Oracle. Why is that?

```
with T as (
    select x,y, row_number() over (order by x,y) as rnum from functions
)
select distinct a.x,a.y from T a, T b 
where a.x = b.y and b.x=a.y and a.x<=a.y and a.rnum!=b.rnum 
order by a.x,a.y;
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't allow `as` for table aliases.  You *could* write the query using this `FROM` clause:

```
from T a cross join
     T b
```

However, that is silly, because you don't intend a `cross join`.  As your query is written, it would be:

```
with T as (
      select x, y, row_number() over (order by x, y) as rnum
      from functions
     )
select distinct a.x, a.y
from T a join
     T b 
     on a.x = b.y and b.x = a.y and a.x <= a.y and a.rnum <> b.rnum 
order by a.x, a.y;
```

If is a bit hard to decipher what this is supposed to be doing.  But I think it is trying to get `x`/`y` combos that appear more than once.  If so, use `count(*)` instead:

```
with f as (
      select x, y, count(*) over (partition by x, y) as cnt
      from functions f
     )
select f.x, f.y
from f
where cnt > 1;
```

This is much simpler and should have better performance too.  And, it should work in all the databases mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok, the second part works. But the last block you wrote using 'count' doesn't work.